# Обращение к активному элементу select в js

Tags: javascript, html, select

Вопрос довольно простой, как в яваскрипт корректно обратиться к содержимому активного "option" элемента "select" хтмл?
Подозреваю, что должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
document.select(1).value(1).focus == true;
```

Но такое условие не работает.

Comment: `document.querySelector('[name="1"]').value` - так, например, можно получить значение первого селекта

Comment: через ивенты или слушатели событий `<select onchange="bw + (sw - this.value);">`

Comment: humster_spb, мне не нужно получать значений списка, мне нужно, чтобы выполнялись заданные действия при выборе тех или иных вариантов списка.

Comment: puffleeck, а через "focus" и "value" этого никак сделать нельзя?

Comment: @drakoblack, focus если и поможет, только если его вешать на каждую опцию отдельно, а change на select вешается, возвращая в код только выбранную опцию. как итог меньше кода, и такой вариант точно рабочий. и да, value у опции используется только когда он задан. если у опции нету этого атрибута, тогда используется содержимое. `<option value="1">это всего лишь название опции</option>`, `<option>а это и название и значение (value) одновременно</option>` p.s. на будущее - лучше закидывать свой код целиком в вопрос. и при обращении к кому то используйте @ перед ником, иначе нет уведомления

Comment: @puffleeck, понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Путем метода проб и ошибок, нашел 2 возможных варианта:

1. Вариант humster_spb:

```
document.querySelector('[name="1"]').value
```

Здесь важный момент, что обращение идет не к содержимому "option", а к его значению "value", которое по умолчанию имеет тип "string", так что если данные нужны для каких-либо математических вычислений, то к данному выражению нужно еще применить функцию "Number()". В противном случае, все математические операции над содержимым "value" будут выполняться так, словно это "string", а не число.

```
Number(document.querySelector('[name="1"]').value);
```

2. Через id элемента: сначала нужно присвоить уникальный id каждой опции, а затем данные элемента выбора можно вызвать следующим выражением:

```
document.getElementById('s22').content;
```

Работает, как с "content" так и с "value".

Стоит отметить, что данные выражения сами по себе уже являются переменными, то есть с ними можно выполнять операции.
Например, если у нас есть переменная A и нам нужно прибавить к ней значение, которое содержится в select.option(1) (первой опции элемента select)
То следующее выражение будет вполне работать:

```
<select name="1">
<option id="b1" value="b">1</option>
<option id="b2" value="d">2</option>
</select>
```

```
let A = 0;
A = A + document.getElementById('b1').content;
Consol.log('Result', A); // A=1;
```

При этом, если использовать вместо "content" "value", но не использовать Number(), то получиться следующее:

```
let A = 0;
A = A + document.getElementById('b1').value;
Consol.log('Result', A); // A=0b1;
```

А с Number():

```
let A = 0;
A = A + Number(document.getElementById('b1').value);
Consol.log('Result', A); // A=Null, так как "b" не является числом и не является какой-либо заданной переменной.
```

Вот если "b" сделать числовой переменной, то это вполне может сработать:

```
let b = 11;
let A = 0;
A = A + Number(document.getElementById('b1').value);
Consol.log('Result', A); // A=11.
```